# In my code for validation i used jquery , in my form if any filed is missing mean it have raise error

Tags: jquery, validation

```
<script>
       $.validate({
           errorMessgaePosition: 'top'
       });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#form1").validate({

                rules:{
                    firstname: "required",
                    lastname : "required",
                    username :{
                                require:true,
                                minlength:2
                    },
                    password :{
                                require: true,
                                minlength: 6
                    },
                    confirm :{
                                require:true,
                                minlength:6,
                                equalTo:"#password"
                    },
                    email :{
                                require:true,
                                email: true
                    },
                    mobile :{
                                require:true,
                                minlength:10
                    },
                    gender :"required"   
                },
                messages:{
                    firstname:"Please first name should not be empty.",
                    lastname :"Please last name should not be empty.",
                    username:{
                                require:"Please username should not be empty.",
                                minlength:"Minimum length of username should be 2."
                    },
                    password :{
                                require:"Please password should not be empty.",
                                minlength:"Password must be  6 character."
                    },
                    confirm:{
                                require:"Please re-type your password.",
                                minlength:"Password must be  6 character.",
                                equalTo :"Password should be equal."
                    },
                    email:{
                                require:"Please email should not be empty.",
                                email:"Please give valid email."
                    },
                    mobile:{
                                require:"Please give mobile no.",
                                minlength:"Mobile no. should be 10 digit."
                    },
                    gender:"Please choose gender."
                },

            submitHandler: function(form){
            /* here other validation codes */

                    form.submit();
            }
        });

      });
    /* this for cancel button */
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".cancel").click(function(){
             validator.resetForm();
         }) ;
      });

/*
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        &("#form1").validate({
            $("#username").focus(function(){
                var firstname= $("#firstname").val();
                var lastname= $("#lastname").val();
                if( firstname && lastname && !this.value)
                {
                    this.value= firstname +"."+ lastname;
                }
            });
        });
});
  */
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>***Registration Form***</h3>
    <form id="form1"  action="#" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div id="box">    
            <div class="label"><label for="firstname">First Name :</label>
                <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" />
            </div>
            <div class="label"><label for="lastname">Last Name : </label>
                <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" />
            </div>

            <div class="label"><label for="username">Username : </label>
                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" />
            </div>
            <div class="label"><label for="password">Password : </label>
                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" />
            </div>
            <div class="label"><label for="confirm">Confirm Password :</label>
                <input id="confirm" type="password" name="confirm"/> 
            </div>
            <div class="label"><label for="email">Email : </label>
                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="label"><label for="mobile">Mobile No. : </label>
                <input id="mobile" type="tel" name="mobile" />
            </div>
            <div class="gender">Gender :
                <input class="gender1" type="radio" name="gender">Male
                <input class="gender1" type="radio" name="gender">Female
            </div>
            <div class="but">   
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                <input id="cancel" type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
            </div>
         </div>  
    </form>
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? You have only provided us with a code block and an ambiguous title with no accompanying description of the problem you are facing. Please update your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a class to the required field and handle it as following:

(Add the class "required" for mandatory textboxes)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $('.required').each(function(i, obj) {
           if($(obj).val()=='')
           {
            $(obj).addClass('req')               
           }
        });
    });
    
        $(document).on("focus", ".req", function () {
            $(this).removeClass("req");
        });
                        
});
```

```css
.req{
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px #F8694D !important;
 border: 1px solid #F8694D !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">    
            <div class="label"><label for="firstname">First Name :</label>
                <input id="firstname" class='required' type="text" name="firstname" />
            </div>
            <div class="label"><label for="lastname">Last Name : </label>
                <input id="lastname" class='required' type="text" name="lastname" />
            </div>

            <div class="label"><label for="username">Username : </label>
                <input id="username" class='required' type="text" name="username" />
            </div>
            <div class="label"><label for="password">Password : </label>
                <input id="password" class='required' type="password" name="password" />
            </div>
            <div class="label"><label for="confirm">Confirm Password :</label>
                <input id="confirm" class='required' type="password" name="confirm"/> 
            </div>
            <div class="label"><label for="email">Email : </label>
                <input id="email" class='required' type="email" name="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="label"><label for="mobile">Mobile No. : </label>
                <input id="mobile" class='required' type="tel" name="mobile" />
            </div>
            <div class="gender">Gender :
                <input class="gender1" type="radio" name="gender">Male
                <input class="gender1" type="radio" name="gender">Female
            </div>
            <div class="but">   
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                <input id="cancel" type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
            </div>
         </div>
```